# How to insert into a MYSQL after submit a form and open a new page

Tags: php, html

I have a survey page and what I need is to insert into a MySql db after end users click the submit, and open a new page says Thank you.

What I did is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
  $Questions = array("Question1");
?>
<form id = "surveyform" method = "POST" >
<label name = "Q">Please share any recommendations you have for improving this program.</label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="100" name="A" form="surveyform" style = "width: 504px"></textarea>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name ="Insert" value="Insert">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Insert'])){
    $A = '';
    if (isset($_POST['A']) && $_POST['A'] !='') {$A = $_POST['A'];}
    $QA = array(array('question'=>$Questions[0], 'answer'=>$A1));
    $InsertSQL = "Insert into table(question, answer) values('".$QA[0]['question']."', ,".$QA[0]['answer']."')";
    $Insert = new Query($InsertSQL);
    $Insert->executeQuery();
    header("Location: /path/thankyou");
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

But it could not insert into the db. It is not the db connection related issue because if I comment out the checking part

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['Insert'])){
}
```

It could write into the db. The problem is when I load the page, it will write empty values into the db, and so I want to add some checking here to make sure the submit button is clicked.

I changed the thankyou.php by move the insert into part to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<h5>Thank you for your time to take the survey. Have a good day!</h5>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so so much. Finally it works!

Comment: You expect to do ***what***? I didn't get it. You pass "Insert" inside GET and expect it to automatically fetch your data, process it and put it into a database, is that it? If it isn't like that (I hope not), please post some more code, like what happens when submit is pressed (what is "/thankyou"? A page?)

Comment: after submit the form, 1.writeinto db 2. open a new page

Comment: But where is the code where you deal with the connection and queries? Where is "thankyou **.php** " part?

Comment: @user5004724 form method should be `post`, `$_REQUEST` change it to `$_POST` and better use `isset` function

Comment: @user5004724 try using `isset()` instead of `!empty()`. also use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. bdw please edit your post and put your MySQL queries!!

Comment: How can you people *diagnose* that's the problem with such small incomplete snippet of a code?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, spend 16 hours daily on SO and you can then easily diagnose the problems too :P BTW welcome to SO

Comment: @Shehary You just patronized me over rep points, is that it? OP didn't *reveal* enough code to make any asserted assumptions, only guess. Aim for jackpots.

Comment: Mr. NaViD. Thank you for your help! I change it to if (isset($_POST['Insert'])){} but not work...

Comment: @user5004724 did you change the form method???`<form method="post" ......>`

Comment: Thank you Aedix Rhinedale ! Do you really need the db operation and thankyou.php parts? I want to keep the question simple. I will say there are no problem with those parts since if I comment out the if check, everything is fine.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, if its all about rep points, won't be leaving the comments instead posted the answer and for the rest, read the ^^^^OP comment

Comment: Mr. NaViD. yes I changed the form method to post also...

Comment: @user5004724 please put your MySQL queries to check if there is any problem!!!

Comment: @user5004724 you should specify the rows you want to insert:`insert into table(row1,row2) values("value1","value2")`

Comment: If you want a redirection, you should point your action to another page, not itself, and place your $_POST handlers there

Comment: @user5004724 also you should use `$` before any variable.So try using `$Insert = new Query($InsertSQL);`

Comment: Thank you Aedix and Mr. NaViD! I will try to insert into the db at the thank you page.

Comment: @user5004724 so what left to resolve?

Comment: Thank you guys! So much!

Answer (score 2):

After reading the comments above, the way I see it you are struggling with following:

> 1) Re-direction.
>
> 2) Query-Insertion.
>
> 3) Opening a Page with a message only.

> For 1)

You could either leave the `action = ""` empty and when using the `$_POST` data give a `header(location: yourpage.php);` or you could give the `action = "youpage.php"` and use all the `$_POST` data there.

> For 2)

You need to specify the row as you give the values in your query, there is a syntax error in it. It should be like `"INSERT INTO table(column1, column2, column3) Values('Value1','Value2','Value3')";`

> For 3)

Redirect the user to an empty page or even better an alert message like `echo <script>alert('Thank you');</script>` at a specific condition, lets say when you have successfully inserted data into the database, as your purpose is to show the message only.

Comment: Thank you HawasKaPujaari! I got frustrated since the problem is still there and I got a -1 from the question. :-)

Comment: I just want to know how to detect the submit and insert into the db. If no detecting, the insert works well. Redirection always works.

Comment: You mean I could use all $_POST data in the newly opened page? Now it is just a Thank you there!

Comment: Thank you HawasKaPujaari! Thank you for your patience and have to guess what my meaning. It works finally! I promise I will learn hard to ask better questions in the  future.

Comment: @user5004724 glad to know you did and it's all good I'm sure you will ace it in no time ;) please tick my answer if it helped you :)